# Accessing class members

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a class `ABC`:

```
class ABC
{
    var l:Label=new Label();
    var m:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
}
```

Given an instance of class `ABC`, e.g. `obj`:

```
var obj:ABC=new ABC();
```

I need to access both `obj.m` and `obj.l`. Say `m` has an eventlistener `fl_listen` which gets triggered on a mouse click:

```
function fl_listen(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
   var k=event.target;
}
```

Within this handler, I can access the `MovieClip` of `ABC` class. However, my requirement demands to access the object of `Label` in the `ABC` class too. Any help will be greatly appreciated, I am rather new to using ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reconsider your architecture.
Why do you have to handle the event in m? Just listen for the events inside of ABC and handle the event there, you have access to both the label and movieclip. If you need to perform some logic inside the movieclip instance m, then handle that and only that in your mc.

Using your pseudo code:

```
public class ABC
{

    var l:Label=new Label();
    var m:MovieClip=new MovieClip();

    function ABC(){
       m.addEventListener(MouseEvent.X,_handleX );
    }

    private function _handleX(e:Event):void{
       //you have access to both. Do what you need:
       m.alpha = 0.4;
       l.text = 'Changed';
    }


}
```

Comment: and reconsider your naming conventions too!